# React Gatsby window is not defined server side

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, gatsby

I'm trying to render either a mobile nav or a regular navbar depending on the width of the window. While deploying to netlify, I get the error that window is not available during server side rendering.  I read the gatsby docs docs on the issue, and I understand that is happening but I cannot figure out the proper way to restructure this since I cannot useState within useEffect and I otherwise deal with scoping of my variables.  Any help would be appreciated!

This is the gatsby documentation: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/

```js
const Layout = ({ children}) => {
  const width = useWindowSize()
  
  let navbar;

  if (width > 936) {
    navbar = <NavBar />
  } else {
    navbar = <MobileNav />
  }

  return (
    <OverflowHidden>
      {navbar}
      <main>{children}</main>
      <Footer/>
    </OverflowHidden>
  )
}

const useWindowSize = () => {
  const [size, setSize] = useState(window.innerWidth) 

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleResize = () => {
      setSize(window.innerWidth)
    }
    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize)
  }, [])

  return size
}

const OverflowHidden = styled.div`
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 100%;
`

export default Layout
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't measure the size of the browser viewport server-side at compile time anyways, so just set a default/fallback value. Also, you need to be sure to clean up the event you've bound when the component unmounts.

I would recommend adding a debounce routine here as well—not all browsers will do this for you, and updating layout constantly while the browser is resizing typically results in rather poor performance.

Altogether, you get something like this:

```js
const useWindowSize = (initialState = "100%", { ttl = 100 } = {}) => {
  // initialState is used before the component mounts client-side
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(initialState)

  useEffect(() => {
    const calculateHeight = debounce(() => {
      setHeight(window.innerHeight)
    }, ttl)

    calculateHeight()
    window.addEventListener("resize", calculateHeight)

    return () => {
      // deregister event listener on component dismount
      window.removeEventListener("resize", calculateHeight)
    }
  }, [ttl])

  return height
}
```